# Python/Matplotlib - Adjusting the spacing between the edge of the plot and the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I adjust the amount of space between the x-axis and the edge of the plot window? My x-axis labels are oriented vertically and they are running off of the edge of the window that Matplotlib draws.

Here's some example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you have an axis object, for example `ax`, then you can access the figure object simply by doing this: `fig = ax.figure`

Comment: Hi, Paul. I have added some example code.

Comment: This was a great example of how to get vertical xtick labels, thanks. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Paul said, you are using figures. You can get a reference to the current figure with gcf() and then set the spacing as per the [FAQ](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#move-the-edge-of-an-axes-to-make-room-for-tick-labels). I've added two lines to your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Just applying `fig.tight_layout()` can solve this without any manual fiddling.

Comment: Indeed, though tight_layout() did not yet exist when this question was asked. And apparently, eight years later, [tight_layout](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html) is still labelled as 'experimental' (however, I expect it to work well in most typical use cases, so your comment is a valuable addition to this answer).